# parfeval issues - too slow or too much RAM

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm having problems effectively using parfeval instead of parfor. I'm doing this to have more control over job scheduling and monitoring progress.

Basically, how do I get a similar efficiency as with parfor while using parfeval?

The parfor implementation with runtime ~1 minute.

```
parfor i = 1 : params.nperm
    sampledData(i) =  parfun( maprf.datam.ModelData( data.spikes(perm(i,:)), data.movie) );
end
```

Parfeval implementation; consumes 13gb ram, crashes Matlab.

```
for i = 1 : params.nperm
  F(i) = parfeval(parfun, 1,  maprf.datam.ModelData( data.spikes(perm(i,:)), data.movie));
end
% Build a waitbar to track progress
h = waitbar(0,'Waiting for FevalFutures to complete...');
results = zeros(1,params.nperm);
for idx = 1:params.nperm
    [completedIdx,thisResult] = fetchNext(F);
    % store the result
    results(completedIdx) = thisResult;
    % update waitbar
    waitbar(idx/params.nperm,h,sprintf('Latest result: %d',thisResult));
end
delete(h)
```

Parfeval with custom scheduler; takes over an hour.

```
MyPool = gcp();
mapJobs = zeros(MyPool.NumWorkers, 1);
for i = 1 : MyPool.NumWorkers
    F(i) = parfeval(parfun, 1, maprf.datam.ModelData(data.spikes(perm(i,:)), data.movie));
    mapJobs(i) = i;
end

% Build a waitbar to track progress
progress = MyPool.NumWorkers;
h = waitbar(progress, 'Waiting for FevalFutures to complete...');
while ~all([F.Read])
    % find next available results
    [completedIdx, thisResult] = fetchNext(F);
    % find which is the actual index of the job
    %                                 idx = map(completedIdx);
    % store the results
    results(completedIdx) = thisResult;
    % first of all we increment the counter of processed jobs
    i = i + 1;
    progress = progress + 1;
    % now we have an available worker at position completedIdx
    if i < params.nperm
        % there are still pending jobs,
        % then we assign the job to the worker
        F(completedIdx) = parfeval(parfun, 1, maprf.datam.ModelData(data.spikes(perm(i,:)), data.movie));
        % and we keep track of which job is being processed by the worker
        mapJobs(completedIdx) = i;
    end
    % finally we update the waitbar for the happiness of the user
    waitbar(progress / params.nperm, h);%, sprintf('Latest result: %d',thisResult));
end
% at this point i should be equal to progress and to params.nperm
assert((i == progress) && (progress == params.nperm)); % only for debug purposes (it raises an error if the condition is not satisfied)
% at this point we delete the pool of workers (or whatever they are) and close the waitbar
cancel(F);
delete(h)
```

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? (There was a memory leak in `parfeval` which was fixed by http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1134654 that bug report)

Comment: Also, how many `parfeval` calls are you making? It's best if you can arrange things so that each evaluation takes on the order of seconds to avoid the overheads involved with creating and scheduling the tasks.

Comment: @Edric, I'm using 2015a, so it shouldn't be that. I'm making on the order of thousands of calls. Each call has to takes currently less than a second, but I need to keep the functions modular since we're planning to roll it out as a toolbox and then it can take minutes or hours.

Comment: If you can, I'd recommend trying R2015b - this generally has better performance than R2015a, and in particular fixes problems with function workspaces grabbing too much stuff (might be especially relevant if `parfun` is an anonymous function handle). Otherwise, I'd be looking at how much data is in the input arguments to `parfeval`, and if any of it is constant - in which case you can use the Worker Object Wrapper: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31972-worker-object-wrapper (aka http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel.pool.constant.html in 15b)

Comment: @Edric, for me it won't be a problem, but since it's intended to be a toolbox it needs to run also on older versions of matlab.

Comment: @Edric, can I pass objects with overloaded referencing methods as parallel.pool.Constant ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94407/discussion-between-edric-and-piotr-sokol).